# Can I do addSubview several times without removeFromSuperview?

Tags: iphone

Do I have to do removeFromSuperview for each addSubview?
For example, viewWillAppear is called whenever pushed view is popped.
If there is addSubview, it is called several times.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {   
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}
```

Comment: Yes you should remove the view on viewDidDisappear or viewDidUnLoad method, other wise its like you are adding many layer on on layer, not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason you would not put that code in viewDidLoad instead? But if you want to keep it in viewDidAppear it's ok. If you add a subview to a superview it's already a subview of, nothing happens. In fact if you add a subview to any view, it will remove it from its previous superview.

Comment: I cannot put it in viewDidLoad because myView is global variable. When pushed view is popped, it is removed. I have to add it again. What do you mean, "it will remove it from its previous superview." ? Do you mean system removes myView from superview before it adds myView? So, I don't have to remove myself.

Comment: yes. it won't let me add a comment that just says yes, so yes

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that's necessary, no - to quote the docs,

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

We have quite a few views in our app that for various reasons we can potentially assign to the same superview multiple times, and this hasn't caused any issues so far.